# How to retrieve data in two different columns and put in one

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to get data that populates in two different columns on one sheet, and put them into a single column on a different sheet. The data populates in columns E and F on sheet1 and I want to also populate it in column D on sheet2. I have shared a portion of my script below:

```
//Section A: Forum Response Data collection.  
 function dewarData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data');
 var entry_date = sheet1.getRange('A2:A350').getValues();
 var entry_shift = sheet1.getRange('B2:B350').getValues();
 var entry_type = sheet1.getRange('D2:D350').getValues();
 var entry_location1 = sheet1.getRange('E2:E350').getValues();
 var entry_location2 = sheet1.getRange('F2:F350').getValues();
 var entry_ser_type = sheet1.getRange('AU2:AU350').getValues();


 // Section B: Prioritized Data Overview into second sheet.
 var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Overview');
 var rngData = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
 var sum_entry_date = sheet2.getRange('A3:A351').setValues(entry_date);
 var sum_shift = sheet2.getRange('B3:B351').setValues(entry_shift);
 var sum_type = sheet2.getRange('C3:C351').setValues(entry_type);
 var sum_location = sheet2.getRange('D3:D351').setValues(entry_location1 && entry_location2);
var sum_ser_type = sheet2.getRange('E3:E351').setValues(entry_ser_type);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

If you don't want the headers:

```
function remapdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let [hs,...vs] = sh1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(([a,b,c,d,e,f])=>[`${e}/${f}`]);
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh2.getRange(1,4,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

if you do want the headers:

```
function remapdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let vs = sh1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(([a,b,c,d,e,f])=>[`${e}/${f}`]);
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh2.getRange(1,4,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//you may wish to adjust the starting row
}
```

Comment: When I try this, "${e}/${f}" populates in the D column instead of the data from the sheet I actually want.

Comment: Those quotation marks are supposed to be backticks. Also, did you change the sheet names?

Comment: Once I changed it to backticks it resolved the problem, thanks.

Comment: I am trying to do this same function again for a different scenario, however I am getting an error for my last line that says, "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues", Here is the new code: `let [vb] = sheet1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,au,az,ba,bb,bc,bd,be])=>[`${az} ${ba} ${bb} ${bc}`]);
sheet2.getRange(3,10,vb.length,vb[0].length).setValues(vb);`. How can I resolve this?